# Rails ActiveRecord: Where conditions on second query of Includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

So I have four tables, `users`, `courses`, `projects`, and `grades`. `courses` has many `projects`, which has many `grades`. I can't give the whole classes, but here's the appropriate associations.

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :grades
end
class Grade < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :grades
end
```

I would like to list out all courses, and within each course I can see all their projects, and their grade for each project. (Keep in mind what I am giving you here is simplified from my actual project.)

So obviously I should use an includes() statement to make this as efficient as possible. Here's what it would look like:

```
Course.includes(projects: [:grades]).all
```

This gives me the course, projects, and grades, separated among three small, efficient queries. This is exactly what I want but the killer issue here is that I only want grades for the current user. So I would normally go

```
Course.includes(projects: [:grades]).where(grades: [user_id: current_user.id])
```

However, this turns the fast slender three queries into one large, slow query with multiple joins. Normally this would be ok, but in my real implementation there is much more going on in the query and adding more joins makes that one query's runtime explode. **So I would like to keep it broken up into smaller queries, such that the where statements for grades and projects are added to their queries, instead of thrown into one giant join.** Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you could start the query from the user up to the course

Comment: Please post the query plans of all the SELECTS. The fact you are joining 3 tables doesn't necessarily introduce big overheads if you have the proper indexes in place. Sometimes, a JOIN is better than multiple queries. The only way to really understand which one is more efficient is to analyze the query plan.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti I can't post the full queries because I'm not in a position where I can share details on our database tables. Like I said in my post, normally a join would be fine, but my full query joins even more tables than this one, and the run time is significantly better in multiple small queries than in the one large one. I know that I **can** do this with joins, I'm trying to see if its possible to do so without.

Comment: You are asking help without providing enough information to evaluate and provide a response. Any response will simply be a guessing.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti I don't need a specific implemenation to my code, I can figure that out from the answer. What I am asking for is this: is there a way to set where clauses of the different queries that are made by includes(). The normal way of setting a where statement turns the includes() into joins(), is there a way to keep the multiple queries done by includes and simply put the WHERE clauses for each table in their respective queries.